# Clarification of W3 css standard media query - "only"

Tags: css, user-agent, media-queries

I want to use the media property to link to different css files based on the user agent.  I am confused by how the keyword "only" is used.   The W3 site states that "The optional “only” keyword can be used to hide the stylesheet from older browsers. The browsers process media queries starting with “only” as if the “only” keyword is not present."  Isn't this a non-statement?  I read it as saying "If the keyword 'only' is present, older browsers ignore it."  Then why use it?  I know I'm missing some vital info here.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7):

The **only** keyword hides style sheets from older browsers that don't support media queries.

Additional information can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 4):

> "If the keyword 'only' is present, older browsers ignore it."

Yep. "it" is specifically CSS3 media queries (most of those you will see), not the limited/stupid earlier media queries.

> Then why use it?

To avoid having the browser detect and process errors: at minimum this means the error console does not fill up with extraneous messages, in many cases it avoids presenting a dialog box and/or a debugger window to the user, and it sometimes even means the browser will not "barf" on your page refusing to show it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Queries like `*` and `only *` are identical representations, so compliant browsers interpret the `only` keyword correctly by removing it from the representation.

Older browsers don't recognize `only`, interpret it as an unknown media type, evaluate the query as `false`, and ignore (skip) the stylesheet.